# How to add a blank column before each table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to format tables in two sheets “start” so they look like the “result” sheet.

My sample file, including three sheets: “start_1”, “start_2” and “result”.
“start_1” and “start_2” are identical.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/n8dwli8v55lw9gl/add_a_blank_column_before_each_table.xls

I add one blank row at top and freeze title rows.

Here are the tasks:

- Add one blank column before each table. The added column must have no fill color and no border. (Each table here is identified by merged cells in the top title row)
- Determine the last column with data and the last row with data so that the blank outer space is hidden.

Code in ThisWorkbook module:

```vb
Option Explicit
    
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim bScrUpdate As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled 'disable ESC key
    bScrUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    If bScrUpdate = True Then Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "result" Then
            ws.Select
            Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    
            Range("A4").Select
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    
            For Each rng In Rows("2:2").Cells
                If rng.MergeCells Then
                    rng.MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Select
                    Selection.Offset(-1, 1).EntireColumn.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                End If
            Next rng
        End If
    Next ws
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If Not Application.ScreenUpdating = bScrUpdate _
      Then Application.ScreenUpdating = bScrUpdate

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt 'enable ESC key

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a column and clear all of its formatting, you can do something like this:

```
Sub InsertCol()
    Columns(1).Insert
    Columns(1).ClearFormats ' might be unnecessary
End Sub
```

If you want to determine the last row/column look at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)